# Bridge Edge Loops is going to opposite side of body along with dark mesh

Tags: mesh, error

I am trying to use the bridge edge loop to connect the torso and hips of a human model, but it creates triangles and looks like a mess. There are an even amount of points to connect. The hips have a dark mesh and white artifact/scuff marks on it in Edit Mode, which I assume to be the problem. I have tried most answers I could find on this site (recalculating normals, adding more vertices, merged vertices by distance, etc.) to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Bridge Edge Loop Mess
[image: Bridge Edge Loop Mess]

Dark Mesh
[image: Dark Mesh]

Comment: Here is the file to the project:  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=vkMbklD3" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/vkMbklD3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mirror modifier on the chest and hip section, but unlike the chest where you modeled only half (as is normal when using mirror), you "completed" the hip section - you can see the left side is still there despite the mirror being turned off (this is also why you were getting the patchy z-fighting pattern with the mirror on, as it was causing overlapping faces).

[image: Mir1]

To fix it, delete the highlighted section, turn the mirror back on, and *bridge edge loops* will work as normal.

[image: Mir2]

Comment: Thank you. I was stuck on this for hours.